# Quick and Efficient way to generate random numbers in Java

Tags: java, random

I am writing a multi-threaded Java program that generates lot of random numbers.

**Additional Details:**
These numbers are used to create a list of random numbers from 0-99 without repetition and such that every number in the range 0-99 exists in the list (In other words, the list contains 100 unique elements in the range 0-99).

**Generating Random Numbers [Things already tried!]**

1. I have an ArrayList of numbers from 0-100. I generate a random number and use it as an index which is used to pop out an element from the `ArrayList`.
2. I have used `Collections.shuffle()`.

Here is the code for approach 1:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
 arr.add(i, i);
}

for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
  int indx = rand.nextInt(arr.size());
  res.add(arr.get(indx));
  arr.remove(indx);
}
```

For second approach, I replaced the second `for` loop with `Collections.shuffle(arr)`.

As generating list of random numbers is the most expensive part of my algorithm, I want to optimize it. This brings me to the questions:

1. What is the fastest way to generate random numbers?
2. What is the fastest way to generate the list of random numbers as described above?

PS:

1. I found `Collections.shuffle()` to be slower than the first approach
2. Someone suggested me using `rngd` to generate random numbers from hardware in Unix. Has anyone tried this before? How do you do that?

Comment: You say you found `Collections.shuffle()` slower than your first approach. May I ask by how much? For 100 numbers, both approaches should take an almost imperceptible amount of time.

Comment: You are generating randomly ordered, unique numbers. Not random numbers. There is a huge difference.

Comment: @dlev I actually did not measure time from within the program. I was using Netbeans profiler. But, in the first case the time was somewhere around 50ms while it was 80ms in the second approach for the whole program

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, sorry for the language! Please edit accordingly.

Comment: @Jeffrey: In mathematics, it is common practice to pull elements (numbers) without repetition. I think it is perfectly valid to name these random numbers.

Comment: @userunknown Random implies that there is an equal probability of every outcome. If you are pulling unique random numbers, that is no longer the case and the numbers are no longer random.

Comment: @Jeffrey: No. Random means unpredictable. There are random distributions which are equal, such that are gaussian, asymetric ones and much more.

Comment: @userunknown Precisely. When generating unique random numbers within a range you can begin to predict which numbers will come next because there are no repeats. The set of numbers will become predicable, and will no longer be random according to your definition.

Comment: @Jeffrey: No. The only predictable number is the last one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem with [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) is that is uses default [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) instance which is a thread-safe singleton. You say that your program is multi-threaded, so I can imagine synchronization in `Random` being a bottle-neck.

If you are happily running on Java 7, simply use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). Look carefully, there is a version of [`shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)) taking `Random` instance explicitly:

```
Collections.shuffle(arr, threadLocalRandom);
```

where `threadLocalRandom` is created only once.

On Java 6 you can simply create a single instance of `Random` once per thread. Note that you shouldn't create a new instance of `Random` per run, unless you can provide random seed every time.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem might be the overhead of the Integer boxing and unboxing.  You might find it helpful to reimplement the Fisher-Yates shuffle directly on an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach woul be to generate the numbers with the `Math.random()` method as in the example [here](http://www.java-examples.com/generate-random-numbers-using-math.random) and initialize the list via a static init block like this:

```
private static List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
static {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // randomize number
    list.add(number);
  }
}
```

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):

```
for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Check [Fischer and Yattes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

Comment: This is exactly what `Collections.shuffle()` is doing.

Comment: Good and bad :-). Good because your pseudo-code is correct. Bad - because the OP already tried it without luck.